# First iteration for loops & wet/dry runs

Tags: python, datetime, compare

So my issue feels a bit complicated, maybe it's just me.. to put it in laymen's terms here's what I'm trying to accomplish.. I need to get the latest line that pertains to the status that you're in, grab the timestamp from it and compare it to current time.

For our program at work it saves to a log file.. the file can get up to 50MB some days.. currently I'm working with the following code to get the latest line:

```
with open(file_location) as file_object:
    for each_line in file_object:
        if "You're currently in: " in each_line:
            recent_statement = eachLine
```

By the end of the run of that snippet it is guaranteed to grab the latest "status" line you're in.

Here's what the full line looks like:

```
Feb  9 12:34:20 You're currently in: Busy
```

Now the issue with how the log files are saved is that there can be duplicates of the same "status" but a different timestamp which can basically reset my timer..

So if current time is 12:56:00 and this is how a log file looks:

```
Feb  9 12:33:00 You're currently in: Away
Feb  9 12:35:00 You're currently in: Away
```

I need it to have the timer say it's been 23 minutes, not 21.. on top of that, if the status changes I need the timer to reset to that new time.

Example:

```
Feb 9 12:48:00 You're currently in: Available
Feb 9 12:49:13 You're currently in: Offline
```

I need it to come back and have the current status which would be `Offline` now and the timer say they have been in that status for 4 minutes.

My current function to accomplish that looks like this...

def check_elapsed(recent_aux_line,aux):
    global dry_run,static_timestamp_recentstatement
    timestamp_recentstatement = timestamp_of_line
    current_time = datetime.now()

```
if dry_run == True:
    elapsed_time = current_time - timestamp_recentstatement
    static_timestamp_recentstatement = timestamp_recentstatement
    dry_run = False
elif dry_run == False:
    elapsed_time = current_time - static_timestamp_recentstatement

print sys_time(),"Person has been in",status,"for",elapsed_time

if elapsed_time > timedelta(minutes=4):
    print "Over 4 minutes!"
```

There has to be an easier way of writing what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: - The formatting of your function is broken; - where does the `status` variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution (if I understood the problem correctly) would be to simply ignore lines that contain the same text as the previous one after `"You're currently in: "`.  You are interested in the timestamp of the last line that wasn't ignored under this condition.

```
ignore_if_equal_to = None
with open(file_location) as file_object:
    for each_line in file_object:
        if "You're currently in: " in each_line:
            trail = each_line.split("You're currently in: ")[1:]
            if trail == ignore_if_equal_to:
                continue
            recent_statement = eachLine
            ignore_if_equal_to = trail
print recent_statement
```